# find folder and copy contents to new folder,

Tags: file, directory, copy, location, delete-file

I am trying to find a folder from its parent directory and then copy the contents only to a different folder, but only the empty folder gets copied and not its content with below. Additionally I would like to remove the contents from the original folder after copying to new location.

```
$a = (Get-ChildItem C:\ProgramData\IsolatedStorage -recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true -and $_.Name -match "AssemFiles"})

$b = "C:\xyz\"

Copy-Item $a –destination $b  -force
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

$a = ((Get-ChildItem C:\ProgramData\IsolatedStorage -recurse | Where-Object {$*.PSIsContainer -eq $true -and $*.Name -match "AssemFiles"}) | Select-Object FullName).FullName
$b = "c:\xyz"
Copy-item "$a*" -Destination $b
Remove-item "$a*"